# How Did the ONI Control the Children?

Tags: video-games, halo, halo-first-strike

In the Halo universe, we know that:

> SPARTAN-II candidates were abducted as children at the age of 5 and raised in a military lifestyle, to know only war, and operated on, for armor augmentations.

How did the ONI control them and keep them in line when first abducted? At that age the kids would royally freak out when realizing where they were later, no longer being home or with family.  Cooperation would be a logistical nightmare to obtain.

Putting them under and keeping them under would have been detrimental to their physical health and to the whole point of the program Halsey developed.

Answer (score 1):

They'd simply control them the same way as people have historically done with children they've recruited and/or abducted and forced into service.

It's rather hard to criticize the portrayal of a fictional organization in a science-fiction setting as being unrealistic in doing this when there's real world example such as the [Small Boys Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Boys_Unit) which have done it in [the very recent past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_children_in_the_military) and militant groups still doing it now.

Comment: Not to mention that Hitler did something like that with the German youth

Comment: Not trying to sound cold about the SBU situation in history, but the ONI didn’t force the kids to kill their families nor just choose kids from poor families to exploit their quality of life for gain. They chose based upon genetic viability regardless of background and family position. Also the SBU didn’t replace the kids with programmed-to-die clones, so the families wouldn’t miss them.

Comment: There was a halo comic I can't remember the name of that covered some of this. I think it mostly concerned an escape by several of them. I remember that two of the kids quit running and went back when they realized they could never go back to their old lives, as they would no longer fit.